# Sort functions by name?

Tags: visual-studio-code, autoformatting

Is it possible to sort functions by name in Visual Studio Code ? I mean, using a keyboard shortcut or even an extension.

Precision: I'm spaeking about sorting the functions in the panel code editor.

Comment: You want it to reorder/format the actual code?

Comment: @epascarello yes :)

Answer (score 34):

If you are here looking for a way to change the order of the **symbols list** for the breadcrumbs (as I was), you can do that via **breadcrumbs.symbolSortOrder** setting (in Visual Code > Settings).

Comment: I think the need is to EDIT the content of the file.

Comment: This is the best workaround until someone figure out how to edit the content of the file though.

Answer (score 30):

Are you aware of the **Outline** view in the Explorer panel?  You can sort by various categories.

See demo.  I have sorted by `Type` to get all the functions together and they are alphabetical.

[image: outline view]

Comment: Thank you! But I would want to actually sort the functions in the code. I know it's possible in Intellij IDE, if I remember well.

Comment: Ahh, an unusual request.  I'll leave this answer for people who get here by searching.

Comment: It's one of this things where if you tried it once you're gonna want it for the rest of your career. NetBeans has it for Java and I'm basically missing it wherever else.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for Python classes 

Comment: @Rafael I would assume that your language server (python extension) doesn't support it yet.

Comment: I take that back... it was "loading" for a while but started working now

Comment: Hi there, did you find a solution ?

Comment: Appears to be a known issue https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/534

Answer (score 5):

If you are using `TypeScript`, take a look at [member-ordering](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/member-ordering/) rule and `alphabetize` option in `tsLint`. for other languages like C#, there are probably extensions out there but I haven't looked them up myself.