# How can I sort the JS variables in a single file alphabetically?

Tags: javascript, typescript, automation, refactoring, code-formatting

I have a JS file with about 1,000 variables that looks like this:

```
export const FruitOrange: React.FC = () => (
    <Trans id="fruit.orange">Orange</Trans>
);
export const FruitApple: React.FC = () => (
    <Trans id="fruit.apple">Apple</Trans>
);
```

I want to sort all the variables in this to be in alphabetical order.

In other words, I want to sort the variable declarations so that `FruitApple` comes before `FruitOrange`.

How can I do this?

- [VSCode cannot do this as of 2023](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59718274/visual-studio-code-sort-functions-by-name).
- I have PHPStorm, and I tried [configuring arrangement rules for JavaScript and TypeScript](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/rearrange-code.html#configure-rules), but even though I set the **Order** for each matching rule to *Order by name*, when I reformat the code, it is not in alphabetical order.

I just need to reformat the file once; any tool that can do this automatically is acceptable; I just don't want to hand-sort 1,000 variables.

Comment: Small note: having c.1000 components doesn't seem like a very cost-effective method to do a translation service.

Comment: I've not tried this so I'll add it as a comment. I would write a macro that put all the lines for an export on a single line, copy and paste 1000 lines into Excel, sort in Excel, paste it back into Intellij and reformat the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make all the variables single line with regex(`.*` toggle) replacer (ctrl+h)
   `\n(?!export)` -> `<<NEWLINE>>`

```
export const FruitOrange: React.FC = () => ( <<NEWLINE>>    <Trans id="fruit.orange">Orange</Trans> <<NEWLINE>>);
export const FruitApple: React.FC = () => ( <<NEWLINE>>    <Trans id="fruit.apple">Apple</Trans> <<NEWLINE>>);
```

2. Select all text(ctrl-a) and use VSCode command `Sort Lines Ascending` from the command pane (ctrl-shift-p)

```
export const FruitApple: React.FC = () => ( <<NEWLINE>>    <Trans id="fruit.apple">Apple</Trans> <<NEWLINE>>);
export const FruitOrange: React.FC = () => ( <<NEWLINE>>    <Trans id="fruit.orange">Orange</Trans> <<NEWLINE>>);
```

3. Restore your newlines back
   `<<NEWLINE>>` -> `\n`

```
export const FruitApple: React.FC = () => (
    <Trans id="fruit.apple">Apple</Trans>
);
export const FruitOrange: React.FC = () => (
    <Trans id="fruit.orange">Orange</Trans>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Use MS Word for example

Copy and paste your code in.

- Control H, search for `^p`  (the trailing space is important, so you only capture the indented lines) and 'Replace All' them with nothing.
- Control H, search for `^p}` and 'Replace All' them with `}`.
- Now each definition is on a single line. In the Home icon-bar thingy, go to the Paragraph section and press Sort (the A->Z icon).

Then copy-paste it back into your code editor, such as VS Code, and get it to reformat.

This should work as long as any multi-line definitions have indentation (which again, VS Code and others should do for you).